# Which one is more appropriate? "we will like to thank you" or "we would like to thank you"?

Tags: grammar

Which one should I use?

> We **will** like to thank you for all your support.

or

> We **would** like to thank you for all your support.

Comment: Use "*would*". And read the Help Center for this site.

Comment: @Dan Bron gives the more common usage, but like everything it depends on what your intended meaning is.  If you want to talk about possibly in the future wanting to thank someone, such as "If you save our village, we will hold a fiesta in your honor and we will want to thank you for all your support at this fiesta." then *we will* is correct.  If you mean you would like to thanks someone *now* or the person has already done something worthy of thanks, then *we would* is correct.

Comment: @Brillig: I doubt that contrived context will help OP understand why he doesn't know how to establish correct usage here. The basic problem is that all he *really* wants to say is *"**We thank** you for [blah blah]"* (where we often delete the ***I/We*** subject and say *"Thank you for that"*). Inserting highly non-intuitive ***would like*** is a formal/deferential device placing irrealis "distance" between the speaker and the expression of his desire to express thanks.

Comment: Also this appears to be addressed here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224660/should-you-use-will-like-or-would-like-for-a-request-response-in-the-present

Answer (score -2):

Which one you use depends on the context (which is universal "it depends" for every language answer!).

> We will like to thank you for all your support.

would be used in the context of discussing a specific event in the future. Such as:

> And after the toast, we will like to thank you for all your support.

Though, you would probably say, "we will thank you for your support," because you are not thanking them at the time, but expressing a future expression of thanks.  Saying that, it's not often that someone would say this and apart from articulating a series of future events, you wouldn't say this.

> We would like to thank you for all your support.

is idiomatic. If you are expressing your appreciation, this is the one to use. It could be used in the future tense in context:

> After the project is done, we would like to thank you for all your support by sending you on a trip.

But, can be used by itself with the same meaning as: "Thank you for your support". However, the way you wrote it is more circumstantial to a ceremony and is more formal. "Thank you for your support" would be used in a more informal setting. Though, there is no hard rule to separate these two; they are interchangeable and can be used in both circumstances.

Comment: I cannot think of a context where "We will like to thank you" is correct.  "We will thank you", yes.  "We will like to thank you", no.  None of your examples look natural to me.

Comment: I only gave two examples, both valid, one is natural. And I spent half my answering explaining how one is natural and the other isn't.

And of the two examples, if "We would like to thank you for your support," doesn't sound natural, then we must speak different dialects of English. I grew up with Canadian English with frequent British vocabulary, moved to the States and picked up the predominantly too-familiar tone and usage and then to the Ozarks where you can hardly understand some people for the lack of words they place in their sentences. I've become proficient in each of these dialects.

Comment: And, but for the backwoods Ozark dialect, "We would like the leave," is natural in all dialects.

"I will take my tea at 2:30 today" and "I will like to take my tea at 2:30 today" are both VERY valid uses of "will like" in British English. Not natural in American English. But again, American English extremes on the too-familiar and casual speech. The same phrase would be absolutely natural in American English as, "I'll thank you for your help [later]," or "Thanks, yo."  But, "We" implies a group or organization and with appreciation, the context uses more formal language.

Comment: @iolympian I suspect that Stephen Dunscombe simply overstated his case. I don't see how the last two blockquotes are anything but standard. However, in constrast, "And after the toast, we will like to thank you for all your support," is contrived to the point that it sounds absurd. Coming up with an example of "we will like..." feels more like a parlor game than  a constructive effort for English language learners. JMO as I know you put a lot of effort into helping the OP.

Comment: @iolympian Do you know of any examples of "I will like to take my tea at 2:30 today" in the wild?

Comment: Actually, yes. That's very standard in British English when speaking with a house worker.